Glide showing only some (randomly) images from Google Drive
I have a quiz app, where I have a category with picture identification, nothing fancy.
To prevent increased app size I decided to store images at Google Drive (seemed as best solution for me, because I can create images on my PC and then stream it to Drive immediatly a more importantly automatically).
BUT my function is showing only some images, and always random ones. Imagine you have 10 quiz questions - first image is loaded, 2nd and 3rd not, but 4th yes and so on. Always randomly. Next time 1st is not loaded, but 2nd yes, 3rd not...
Function code:
private void loadImage(String id, ImageView mainImage){
    Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(BASE_URL + id)
            .fitCenter()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .dontAnimate()
            .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    assert e != null;
                    for (Throwable t : e.getRootCauses()) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "Caused by", t);
                    }
                    e.logRootCauses("TAG");
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image ready!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(mainImage);
}

BASE_URL is standard "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=" and id is fetched as a question from array
Logcat error:
E  Caused by com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:98)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:122)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:58)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:95)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:88)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:311)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:277)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultPriorityThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:380)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:214)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:263)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:217)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:307)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:301)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:197)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:188)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:129)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:750)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:622)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:475)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:248)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:95)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:122) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:58) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:95) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:88) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:311) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:277) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:421) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultPriorityThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:380) 
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:119)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:176)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:936)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:900)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readUntilDataAvailable(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:815)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:788)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:138)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:213)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:307) 
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:301) 
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:197) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:188) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:129) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:750) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:622) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:475) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:248) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211) 
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:95) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:122) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:58) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:95) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:88) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:311) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:277) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:421) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultPriorityThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:380) 

I mean status code -1? I'm used for Http exceptions 400-500 but -1?
I tried to make sense of the error, but that's to much for me, I'm not that experienced with https and stuff.
Thanks for any help!
